# Friendly suffixes after a person's name

Tags: grammar, suffixes

How many suffixes there are to refer to somebody in a friendly way?

I know ～ん／～っち／～べ, but I would like to know if there are more.

Is there any rule to use them? For example, are the following uses natural?

めぐみ (♀) → めぐみん／めぐみっち／めぐみべ

ゆきの (♀) → ゆきのん／ゆきのっち／ゆきのべ

あきら (♂) → あきらん／あきらっち／あきらべ

Answer (score 2):

-べ (*-be*) is very rare as a name suffix. Perhaps you mean **-(っ)ぺ** (*-ppe*), such as in めぐっぺ, ゆきっぺ and すみぺ? Other popular ones include -たん, -すけ, -どん, -りん, -きち, -にゃん and so on.

Note that these are not standardized name suffixes but conventions to form nicknames, so it's impossible to count them precisely. For example, if an anime character becomes popular, similar nicknames become trendy, and may be forgotten a few years later. In addition, if someone's nicknames has been established, you generally cannot call them in other ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just one doubt, then all this suffixes: ～ん／～っち／～(っ)ぺ and -たん, -すけ, -どん, -りん, -きち, -にゃん can be used with any name or for example, for female names some are more common and for male names others are more common? Is there also any rule (even if not standarized) of which suffix is more common to use depending on the kana in which each name ends?

Comment: @kanachan It is difficult for Japanese people to strictly verbalize such rules because they often choose them based on intuition, but it's definitely not arbitrary. Basically they are used similarly to [those suffixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive#Examples) in English. There are gender tendencies, but some suffixes, including すけ, are originally for males, but now tend to be attached to female nicknames.